# Disable help-menu on mouse button at a right side (with x-coord > 0x7F)

Tags: emacs

When I click, or scroll mouse wheel, and it's pointer is at the right part of the screen, where there no text, emacs shows help-menu like this:

```
Press PageUp key to reach this buffer from the minibuffer.
Alternatively, you can use Up/Down keys (or your History keys) to change
--/.../--
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
e==>Emacs Tutorial                     E==>Emacs Tutorial (choose language)...
--/.../--
a==>About Emacs                        A==>About GNU
=================================================================================

;; here my work buffer

=================================================================================
Help (up/down to change, PgUp to menu): e==>Emacs Tutorial
```

It is very disturbing, i have to press C-g to return to edit.
How to disable this feature?

P. S. I tried to press C-h k < LMB at right>, but it doesn't show the code of the key, it shows that menu again.

**edit**(in response to Stefan):

after pressing: `aaa <LMB at right> C-g C-h l` i see the following sequence:

... a a a ESC
   [ M SPC \300\256 6 ESC [ M # \300\256 6 C-g C-h l

As I found, those symbols: `\300\256` and `6` are dependent on the position of the cursor when i click. `\300\256` is a smth like horisontal coordinate, `6` is a vertical coordinate.

I investigated it further: the menu appears when y coordinate from an ordinary symbol like `a` or `}` or `DEL`(actually it is the last ordinary symbol) becomes a code like `\300\200`( this is the first value, which cause the help-menu). As a unicode [symbol table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) tells, `DEL` code is U+007F(0b01111111), and the next value will be U+00800(0b10000000) (Padding Character) which is in another table: C1 controls and Latin-1 supplement

I use GNU emacs 23.2.1, over PuTTy ssh client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug.
Here is a workaround for it:

```
;; Disable menubar
(menu-bar-mode -1)

;; Workaround for "mouse on menu-bar" bug
(defun transform-to-start-event (event)
  (let ((y0 (second (window-inside-edges (selected-window))))
        (x0 (first (window-inside-edges (selected-window)))))
    (let ((x (- (car (third (second event))) #x3fff00 x0))
          (y (- (cdr (third (second event))) y0))
          (time (fourth (second event))))
      `(down-mouse-1 ,(posn-at-x-y x y (window-at 0 0) t)))))

(defun tmm-menubar-mouse (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((evt (transform-to-start-event event)))
    (push (cons 'up-mouse-1 (cdr evt)) unread-command-events)
    (mouse-drag-track evt t)))
```

It deactivates the menu bar, but i didn't need it anyway.
Also it doesn't handles selection, and scrolling properly, but at least, it positions point correctly.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. This fixed the same issue for me, using terminal based emacs in an ssh session.

Answer (score 1):

That does not sound like any of the features of Emacs in its default configuration.  I suggest you try: `a a a <LMB at right>` and then `C-h l` which should show you the last few events that Emacs received.  Try to figure out among these which events correspond to  (they will appear right after the `a a a`) to see what the OS sends to Emacs when you do this .

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it the day after tomorrow, when i get access to that machine, and report the result

Comment: Tried it: 
   ... a a a ESC
   [ M SPC \300\256 6 ESC [ M # \300\256 6 C-g C-h l

Comment: @Necto: Aha!  Sounds like it might be an Emacs feature after all, the funny byte sequence is probably the encoding of the clicks (done by Putty), and apparently Emacs incorrectly thinks these bytes mean that you're clicking on the top-line (the one that shows the menu-bar).  You might want to `M-x report-emacs-bug` so that someone more knowledgeable about this code can try and figure out what goes wrong.  Maybe it's fixed in a more recent version of Emacs (no guarantee, but worth a try).