# How to get a text position by x,y coordinates in a specified buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have coordinates of some point in the buffer : x,y relatively to the beginning of a window;
Ho to get a textual-position (offset of the beginning of the buffer) by these relative coordinates?

I. e.:

--------------- starting of the buffer

```
sdfv efrv s
```

========================================= <-- window start border

```
s!df verg 34v dc
sd sdf
```

========================================= <-- window end border

If the point is in the exclamation mark position, than x = 1, y = 0, position = 13. Now i know the (x,y)=(1,0), how to get a position?

**edit**(in response to Stefan)**:**
This coordinates are come from event, fairing on mause-1 down. I take it from a function `tmm-menubar-mouse`. the whole event looks like this:

(mouse-1 (nil menu-bar (45 . 0) 15023 nil 2924 (45 . 0) nil (0 . 0) (1 . 0)))

The problem is, that due to a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317844/disable-help-menu-on-mouse-button-at-a-right-side-with-x-coord-0x7f) some coordinates are calculated wrongly, and i recalculate them, but then i have to get a textual position in order to transmit a new event to `mouse-drag-region`. I get window by `window-at`, and recalculate absolute coordinates to relative substracting window up-left angle from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you try `posn-at-x-y`, although these X and Y are pixel positions whereas you seem to say that you have "character-cell" positions instead.  If that doesn't work, please explain better where your X and Y come from, since there are various definitions of such "character-cell positions" depending on how they handle variable-sized characters like TABs, proportional fonts, images, ...

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what i asked for! Fortunately, it gives all extra needed info.