# Emacs: disable pop-up menus on mouse clicks

Tags: emacs

I would like to know if there is a function to disable the pop-up menus in Emacs. I'm seeing a problem when I use Emacs in Putty (ssh session)... when I click/scroll on the right half of my terminal, the Help pop-up menu comes up... How do I debug this? It is really annoying when I open multiple buffers.

when I click on the right half I see the following:

```
Press PageUp key to reach this buffer from the minibuffer.
Alternatively, you can use Up/Down keys (or your History keys) to change
the item in the minibuffer, and press RET when you are done, or press the
marked letters to pick up your choice.  Type C-g or ESC ESC ESC to cancel.
Click <mouse-2> on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
e==>Emacs Tutorial                     E==>Emacs Tutorial (choose language)...
f==>Emacs FAQ                          n==>Emacs News
k==>Emacs Known Problems               s==>Send Bug Report...
p==>Emacs Psychotherapist              S==>Search Documentation
d==>Describe                           r==>Read the Emacs Manual
m==>More Manuals                       F==>Find Emacs Packages
P==>External Packages                  g==>Getting New Versions
c==>Copying Conditions                 0==>(Non)Warranty
a==>About Emacs                        A==>About GNU

Help (up/down to change, PgUp to menu): e==>Emacs Tutorial
```

I found the same question [here (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317844/disable-help-menu-on-mouse-button-at-a-right-side-with-x-coord-0x7f), But the solution there disables scrolling and selection. I would like to know if there is a solution for this.

Thanks,
asp.

Comment: Try hitting `C-h k` before doing whatever makes that menu pop up. That should let you know what Emacs thinks you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

It hard to know what keybinding is making the menu appear, but you can disable it completely.  Use:

```
(fset 'menu-bar-open nil)
```

That looks kind of a "drastic" solution, so if you don't like it you can learn more about what is making the menu appear by typing "C-h l" just after you see the menu.  You will see the last key/mouse events, the you can use "C-h k" to know the functions those events are invoking and/or rebind them.